# How to log users in with facebook, without having them registered using it initially?

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

I am adding a **Login with Facebook** button to my Larvel web app. Users can already register using an email and a password, So what I need to do is to give the users the ability to Login with Facebook, without having to register using Facebook from the beginning. I have already accomplished this, but I facing a security issue.

The authentication flow goes like this once a user cliks the **Login with Facebook** button:

Redirect users to facebook -> Users enter their email and password -> Facebook returns the user object back -> If the email returned with the user object exists in my database, log the email owner in.

Mostly you have already noticed the problem, but if not, consider this case:

If a user registers with their email in my application, and happens to not have a facebook account associated with that email, then anyone can register a new facebook account with that email, and then just simply log in into my application (Because that email exists in my database!!)

I have been googling this for quite a while now, and it seems like there's no one mentioning this problem, I am assuming this is because I might just be doing it the wrong way!, or maybe it's just done this way! Not really sure.

So, I am seeking guidance, how is this done right?

Comment: Are you sure about the assumptions you are making?  As far as I know, Facebook requires confirmation to set up an account by email address.  And if an attacker has access to the email address to confirm it, they could just as easily perform a standard password reset.

Comment: You can create an account with a phone number and verify it, then update your profile and add an email, it would require virification but you don't have to verify it , it's just for hacking the other account as you see

Comment: Are you certain that an unverified email account would allow you to log in?  Have you tested this?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but to my knowledge, yes If it is verified using something else like a phone number...but now you are bringing doubts to my thinking!

Comment: The Facebook API will not return an email address, unless it has been verified.